# Array of BindableObjects SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, protocols, swiftui

So I'm trying to setup CoreData with SwiftUI and both the CoreData model and SwiftUI views are working. All I need to do is connect them. I am able to pass a discrete number of BindableObjects but what I need is to pass an array. Here's the setup:

```
let peristence = PersistenceManager()
var model = [Entry]() // Entry Conforms to NSManagedObject and BindableObject
let request = Entry.createFetchRequest()
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "callsign", ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
do {
    model = try peristence.persistenceContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
} catch {
    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
}

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(model))
```

Which produces the following error:

> Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that '[Entry]' conform to 'BindableObject'

How would I make `[Entry]` conformant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate that implements BindableObject protocol and forwards the changes on a NSFetchedResultsController

```swift
class BindableFetchedResults<ResultType>: NSObject, BindableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate where ResultType : NSFetchRequestResult {

    let controller: NSFetchedResultsController<ResultType>
    var results: [ResultType]? {
        controller.fetchedObjects
    }
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    init?(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ResultType>, managedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        super.init()
        self.controller.delegate = self
        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        didChange.send()
    }
}
```

In the code, something like this:

```swift
let persistence = PersistenceManager()
let request = Entry.createFetchRequest()
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "callsign", ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

guard let model =  BindableFetchedResults(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: persistence.persistenceContainer.viewContext) else {
    fatalError()
}

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(model))
```

Then you can access the entities on model.results